# Make a div background visible on neighboring divs

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

Have 2x divs (contactInfo & contactForm) within a parent div (ContactUsStyles).  The div, contactForm, has a background image that is behind the contact form.  Problem is the divs does have a fixed width (configured using flexbox) and the background is cut off on the edges of the div (contactForm).  I want the background to flow over and be visible on the other divs as well.

My CSS styling is obviously wrong, just not sure where.

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {
  StyledTextField1,
  StyledTextArea1
} from "./smallComponents/StyledTextField";
import blueFigure from "../img/blue_figure.svg";
import greenFigure from "../img/green_figure.svg";
import { GetInTouchButtonYellow } from "./BackButton";
import validateEmail from "./smallComponents/isValidEmail";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 200
  }
}));

const ContactUsStyles = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${blueFigure});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: -620px;
  height: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background-size: 2000px;
  .contactInfo {
    background-image: url(${greenFigure});
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 688px;
    width: 523px;
    margin-top: 129px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    .title {
      margin-top: 6.9rem;
      height: 89px;
      font-family: Akrobat;
      font-size: 89px;
      font-weight: 100;
      font-stretch: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: normal;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      text-align: center;
      color: #ffffff;
      margin-bottom: 5rem;
    }
    p {
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 2rem;
    }
    a {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 2rem;
    }
  }
  .social-container {
    margin-top: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .icon-small {
    fill: #3776ff;
    fill: #fff;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
  }
  .contactForm {
    /* background-image: url(${blueFigure});
    background-repeat: no-repeat; */
    /* background-position-x: -620px; */
    /* background-size: 2000px; */
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    width: 400px;
  }
`;

function ContactUs() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    cell: "",
    message: "",
    email: ""
  });
  const classes = useStyles();
  const handleChange = name => e => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <ContactUsStyles>
      <div className="contactInfo">
        <div className="title">CONTACT</div>
        <p>087 806 6094</p>
        <p>
          <a href="mailto: info@lighttree.co.za">info@lighttree.co.za</a>
        </p>
        <div className="social-container">
          <div className="social-container-icon">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 28 28" className="icon-small">
                <path d="M19.9 0H3.1C1.387 0 0 1.327 0 2.965v16.07C0 20.673 1.388 22 3.1 22h8.286l.014-7.862H9.264a.493.493 0 0 1-.503-.48l-.01-2.534a.493.493 0 0 1 .503-.484h2.132V8.192c0-2.842 1.814-4.389 4.464-4.389h2.175c.278 0 .504.216.504.482v2.137a.493.493 0 0 1-.504.482h-1.334c-1.442 0-1.72.655-1.72 1.617v2.12h3.166a.49.49 0 0 1 .5.538l-.314 2.534a.497.497 0 0 1-.5.425h-2.839L14.97 22h4.93c1.712 0 3.1-1.327 3.1-2.964V2.965C23 1.327 21.612 0 19.9 0z" />
              </svg>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="social-container-icon">
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 28 28" className="icon-small">
                <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                  <rect width="23" height="22" fill="#FFF" rx="3" />
                  <path
                    fill="#73C59E"
                    d="M3.367 16.27a10.251 10.251 0 0 0 5.268 1.437c5.443 0 9.855-4.156 9.855-9.283 0-.128-.003-.255-.008-.382.197-.146 1.415-1.065 1.713-1.656 0 0-.989.387-1.956.478h-.007l.006-.002c.089-.056 1.335-.856 1.504-1.808 0 0-.7.351-1.678.66-.162.05-.332.1-.507.146a3.55 3.55 0 0 0-2.524-1.03c-1.91 0-3.459 1.457-3.459 3.255 0 .254.031.5.09.738-.267-.01-4.332-.225-7.098-3.38 0 0-1.653 2.126.985 4.311 0 0-.802-.03-1.493-.42 0 0-.254 2.576 2.733 3.234 0 0-.588.21-1.526.06 0 0 .525 2.08 3.179 2.275 0 0-2.099 1.786-5.078 1.367z"
                  />
                </g>
              </svg>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="contactForm">
        <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
          <StyledTextField1
            Label={"Name"}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            fieldType={"name"}
          />
          <StyledTextField1
            Label={"Surname"}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            fieldType={"surname"}
          />
          <StyledTextField1
            Label={"Email"}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            fieldType={"email"}
            validateEmail={validateEmail(values.email)}
          />
          <StyledTextField1
            Label={"Cellphone Number"}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            fieldType={"cell"}
          />
          <StyledTextArea1
            Label={"Message"}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            fieldType={"message"}
          />
          <GetInTouchButtonYellow />
        </form>
      </div>
    </ContactUsStyles>
  );
}

export default ContactUs;
```

> Picture of current issue:
>   [image]
>
> Picture of what we want to achieve:
>   [image]

Appreciate any and all assistance.

Comment: Can you add this to a sandbox so we can play with it?

Comment: I'm sure I can.  Give me a few minutes

Comment: I have added all the code and images to Codesandbox but for some reason its not rendering the same as on my Mac.  (I am new to CodeSandbox, maybe i did something wrong):
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/asdutoit/Lighttree-React

Comment: Thank you for sharing it. I can't render well in my pc aswell don't know why. I assumed you tried working with the css properties overflow and z-index?

Comment: Honestly, no I haven't used overflow or z-index.  Ill try that in just a bit

Comment: What you can also try is setting the background color so that is has opacity and you can see trough. Unless the problem is more complicated but i can't test myself without the working sandbox

Comment: Ok I have tried the z-index and background-color: transparent options but with no success.  I may have added it in the wrong css sections.  Anyway, I have updated the sandbox to now show the images.   (Seems the sandbox doesn't like SVGs, so I swapped it with PNGs)

Comment: I'm still not able to see the images, is the link the same?

Comment: It was supposed to be, but I noticed it did change:  https://codesandbox.io/s/lighttree-provisioning-platform-6uqv9

Comment: I just looked your example on sandbox and it does not seem to have the problem you are describing, can you tell me how to replicate it? @Stephan Du Toit

Comment: The reason, it may seem like there is no problem is that the blue figure has been attached to a parent div, which at first glance, may seem to resolve the issue, but if the viewport is enlarged, you will noticed the bottom left part of the figure is cut off.  Anyway, I have updated the code to have the Blue figure look as per this post.